# Algorithm for polygon intersection

Tags: algorithm, polygon

In my code, I'm generating a polygon for the description of a region.

This polygon is created by a semplification of a 34000-vertices polygon, given at the beginning of the code.

But in the semplification I have to use, I've found this problem: sometimes it generates intersections of sides. I'm asking for algorithm useful to detect intersections.

Comment: Not completely clear what you are asking here. Are you looking for a way to detect if a closed curve is a self-intersecting?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'm an italian student. Yes, I'm looking for that

Comment: I meant no offense and I did not mean the language(I am also not a native speaker). Are you only looking for a boolean result i.e. true/false or you also need to find the intersection?

Comment: If possible, I need to find the intersections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the algorithms for polygons....

http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html

Hope could be helpful for someone else!

Comment: While this is a great introduction to the *Bentley-Ottmann* Algorithm. This code only has code to test for a **single** intersection. (`simple_Polygon`)